# How did Trip enter the alien city unaffected?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In Agents of Shield [S02E10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D._%28season_2%29), Trip returned to the alien city without Fitz and Simmons and, more importantly, without the hazmat suit to disarm the bombs. How did he not get infected with whatever that befell Mack in the episode earlier?

Coulson, Raina, and Skye also went to the alien city without any extra protection and didn't get affected. Nonetheless, as far as these alien/Kree matters were concerned, those 3 had legitimate reasons to be special. What was exceptional about Trip that gave him a similar immunity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trip, Fitz, and Simmons were not affected because they didn't trip the zombification/security system like Mack did. The protective suits Trip, Fitz and Simmons wore down into the temple seemed to have nothing to do with it.

Mack was actually fine at the bottom of the temple originally.

[image: mack is fine!]

Then he decided to touch the patterns on the ground.

[image: no touching!]

This activates the zombification-security system.

[image: oh you done it now, boy]

[image: oooh glowy lights]

And he is then zombified/enslaved by the temple.

[image: my hand went bad]

Raina displays control over Mack, so it's possible that Skye and Raina's "special" natures may have afforded them additional protection against the enslavement, but we don't see them tripping the security either.

Coulson may or may not have been afforded protection due to his GH-235 infused blood, but he had no control over Mack.

Whether or not Fitz, Simmons or Trip could have touched the patterns while wearing the protective suits and *not* triggered the security remains unexplained, since Mack touched it with his bare hands.

Comment: As an aside, this security system seems to be the worst one ever devised. It can completely enslave anyone, but seemingly only if they specifically touch a pattern on the floor.

Comment: Great answer and nice photos! I was thinking of an alternative explanation: Raina went to the city with the key (i.e. the Obelisk) so that might have disabled the security system. It's sort of like: anybody could enter the car after the owner properly disarmed it.

Comment: @yurnero that's certainly possible, but the only thing we see happen with the diviner inside the city is when it's placed on the stand. It could be a cut scene or sloppy writing, but based on what ended up in the episode, this is the theory that makes the most sense to me.